# How to interpret the summary of a keras model with multiple outputs?

Tags: r, keras

Given the following the code:

```
input<-layer_input(shape=2)
hidden<-layer_dense(input,units=4,activation="sigmoid",use_bias=T)
outputs<- list(
  layer_dense(hidden,units=1,activation="linear",use_bias=F),
  layer_dense(hidden,units=1,activation="linear",use_bias=F)
)
model<-keras_model(inputs=input, outputs=outputs)
summary(model)
```

The output of the summary call is the following:

```
Model
Model: "model_63"
____________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                                    Output Shape                     Param #           Connected to                                     
====================================================================================================================================================
input_63 (InputLayer)                           [(None, 2)]                      0                                                                  
____________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_85 (Dense)                                (None, 4)                        12                input_63[0][0]                                   
____________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_86 (Dense)                                (None, 1)                        4                 dense_85[0][0]                                   
____________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_87 (Dense)                                (None, 1)                        4                 dense_85[0][0]                                   
====================================================================================================================================================
Total params: 20
Trainable params: 20
Non-trainable params: 0
```

Somehow (not shown here) the network does not behave as expected. I suspect that something with the architecture is wrong. What I want is a network with two input neurons, 4 hidden neurons and 2 linear output neurons.
What do the number in the brackets in the connected-to column mean?

Comment: Why have you defined the output layer with `layer_dense(hidden,units=1,activation="linear",use_bias=F)` instead of `layer_dense(hidden,units=2,activation="linear",use_bias=F)`?

Answer (score 1):

You designed model does exactly what you described there. Connected to means to which previous layer the current layer is attached, in your case dense_85[0][0] would mean all 4 previous neurons, but not their biases -- as it should be. dense_85 has two parts; [0] is layer of 8 params, 4 for each input feature, then [1] would be 4 params which represent their biases -- the liner addition before activation function.

Breaking last layer into two parts has actually zero effect. Why? Because you created 4 weights, 1 for each of the neurons in previous layer 2 times; 4 x 1 x 2 -- and it would be exactly the same, if you would create 8 weights at once -- 1 for each output -- 4 x 2. Even when you add biases it is still the same. Breaking outputs has effect when you want to do some complicated layers onward, or have different complicated loss functions for each of them.

For visulization try using `deepviz::plot_model`, it really nice plotting and you can more easily see what your model does. Also I recommend increasing layer size or perhaps adding extra layers, if you want to increase model capacity.